# Can "protobuf package" be omitted when using?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have the following protobuf files and I want to compile them into C# using “protobuf-gen”. I found that "chassis.proto" can succeed, but "perception_lane.proto" does not. I guess the reason is "common.Header", which should be "apollo.common.Header":

I compiled bazel in C++ and they didn't have this problem. Aslo can be compiled into python using protoc. The question is whether protobuf itself supports this usage? Or “protobuf-net” does not recognize such usage ？

header.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package apollo.common;

import "modules/common/proto/error_code.proto";

message Header {

  optional double timestamp_sec = 1;
  ...
}
```

chassis.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package apollo.canbus;

import "modules/common/proto/header.proto";

message Chassis {
  optional apollo.common.Header header = 19;
}
```

perception_lane.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package apollo.perception;

import "modules/common/proto/header.proto";


message PerceptionLanes {
    optional common.Header header = 1;
}
```

I got the error message below:

```
C:\01code\protobuf-net-2.3.16\src\protogen\bin\Release\net462>protogen.exe --proto_path=../net462 --csharp_out=gen +names=original +langver=3 modules/perception/proto/perception_lane.proto
modules/perception/proto/perception_lane.proto(9,14,9,27): error: type not found: 'common.Header'
modules/perception/proto/perception_lane.proto(11,14,11,36): error: type not found: 'camera.CameraErrorCode'
modules/perception/proto/perception_lane.proto(12,14,12,37): error: type not found: 'camera.CameraCalibrator'
modules/perception/proto/perception_lane.proto(13,14,13,35): error: type not found: 'camera.CameraLaneLine'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(50,14,50,28): error: type not found: 'common.Point2D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(51,14,51,28): error: type not found: 'common.Point2D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(62,14,62,28): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(64,14,64,28): error: type not found: 'common.Point2D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(96,14,96,28): error: type not found: 'common.Point2D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(97,14,97,28): error: type not found: 'common.Point2D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(98,14,98,28): error: type not found: 'common.Point2D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto(104,14,104,27): error: type not found: 'common.Header'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(30,12,30,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(36,12,36,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(48,12,48,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(51,12,51,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(58,12,58,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(86,12,86,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(89,12,89,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(93,12,93,26): error: type not found: 'common.Point3D'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(157,12,157,25): error: type not found: 'common.Header'
modules/perception/proto/perception_obstacle.proto(158,12,158,28): error: type not found: 'common.ErrorCode'
modules/perception/proto/perception_lane.proto(5,8,5,41): warning: import not used: 'modules/common/proto/header.proto'
modules/perception/proto/perception_lane.proto(6,8,6,56): warning: import not used: 'modules/perception/proto/perception_camera.proto'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds simply like a bug in the name resolution in protobuf-net.Reflection; probably best to log on GitHub with enough info to reproduce it (ideally minimal!). Or even better: you could fork, fix and PR :)

As a workaround, you could try using fully qualified names (starting with `.`) in the schema. For example, `Empty` is `.google.protobuf.Empty` IIRC.

Comment: Thx! I used fully qualified names and successfully built them into c#. But it really took me some time. I will fork in github and see what's the problem.

Comment: @dahohu527 ooh, I do actually have a branch where I've tweaked the name resolution for another report - it *could* be the same thing? Maybe see if the branch fixes it? (I'm on mobile right now,hard to find it)